# Istio Egress Gateway: use different port than default ones

Tags: istio

**Question**

The aim is, that all external requests are routed through the same egress gateway. I have two different ports that I need to reach on the same external service: 8443 and 8888. Reaching port 8443 isn't a problem, but I can't seem to get the port 8888 up and running.

**Additional Information**

I've changed the IstioOperator so that the ingressGateway and the egressGateway can handle additional ports than only the default ones.

Istio Version: 1.7.0

While everything is fine with the ingressGateway definition (ports are exposed and reachable) it is not the case for the egressGateway. In the egressGateway I still can only reach the default ports.
While the service is showing the ports, there is no envoy listening when querying netstat.

**Ingress**

```
istio-ingressgateway       LoadBalancer       X.X.X.X        X.X.X.X              status-port:15021►32047 http2:80►31704 https:443►30924 tls:15443►30250 tcp-syslog:6514►30382       91d
```

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/pilot-agent       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15021           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/envoy            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/envoy            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6514            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/envoy            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/envoy            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:15000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/envoy            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/envoy
```

**Egress**

```
istio-egressgateway        ClusterIP          X.X.X.X                             http2:80►0 https:443►0 tls:15443►0 https-alt:8888►0
```

Here I'm missing an envoy listening on port 8888:

```
istio-proxy@istio-egressgateway-5d6b6df7fd-gzkl6:/$ netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/envoy            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:15000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/envoy            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/envoy            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/pilot-agent       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15021           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/envoy
```

That's the reason (I think) that I'm getting a Failed to connect to upstream error (I've already checked [mutual TLS configuration conflicts](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/#503-errors-after-setting-destination-rule)) - And my config for the 443 port is working:

istio-proxy [2020-12-09T12:09:46.337Z] "- - -" 0 UF,URX "-" "-" 0 0 3 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "x.x.x.x:8888" outbound|8888||istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local - x.x.x.x:8888 x.x.x.x:43362 - -

**Istio Operator**

```
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istio-control-plane
spec:
  tag: 1.7.0

  meshConfig:
    # Enable SDS for proxies
    defaultConfig:
      sds:
        enabled: true
    # Enable access logging for proxies
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout

  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          service:
            # Set designated IP for ingress gateways
            loadBalancerIP: "{{ .Values.istioIngressgatewayIp }}"
            ports:
              # WARNING: Include default ports because Helm replaces the `ports` value
              - port: 15021
                targetPort: 15021
                name: status-port
              - port: 80
                targetPort: 8080
                name: http2
              - port: 443
                targetPort: 8443
                name: https
              - port: 15443
                targetPort: 15443
                name: tls
              # Enable syslog port
              - port: 6514
                targetPort: 6514
                name: tcp-syslog
          hpaSpec:
            minReplicas: 2

    egressGateways:
      - name: istio-egressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          service:
            ports:
            - name: http2
              port: 80
              targetPort: 8080
            - name: https
              port: 443
              targetPort: 8443
            - name: tls
              port: 15443
              targetPort: 15443
            - name: https-alt
              port: 8888
              targetPort: 8888
          hpaSpec:
            minReplicas: 2
```

Do I miss something? Do I need to restart something what I've forgot after adding the additional port for the egress gateway? Or is that not possible to do?

**Gateway**

The used Gateway definition

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: t-egressgateway-$(ENVIRONMENT)
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: tls-t-egressgateway-$(ENVIRONMENT)
        protocol: TLS
      hosts:
        - t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
      tls:
        mode: PASSTHROUGH
    - port:
        number: 8888
        name: tls-t-egressgateway-8888-$(ENVIRONMENT)
        protocol: TLS
      hosts:
        - t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
      tls:
        mode: PASSTHROUGH
```

**Kubectl Describe**

```
Name:         istio-egressgateway-5d6b6df7fd-gzkl6
Namespace:    istio-system
Priority:     0
Node:         9ad0dc92-6865-44a5-9c73-8a99ac9c9f82/xx.x.xx.xx
Start Time:   Wed, 09 Dec 2020 11:19:58 +0100
Labels:       app=istio-egressgateway
              chart=gateways
              heritage=Tiller
              istio=egressgateway
              pod-template-hash=5d6b6df7fd
              release=istio
              service.istio.io/canonical-name=istio-egressgateway
              service.istio.io/canonical-revision=latest
Annotations:  k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/network-status:
                [
                  {
                    "interface": "eth0",
                    "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
                    "ip": "xx.xx.x.xx/24",
                    "name": "cluster-wide-default",
                    "gateway_ip": "xx.xx.x.x",
                    "attachment_id": "8a86dc06-a7d2-4808-98f9-67dce50caec4",
                    "default": true,
                    "vlan_id": 24
                  }
                ]
              kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2020-11-19T07:59:59+02:00
              kubernetes.io/psp: pks-privileged
              prometheus.io/path: /stats/prometheus
              prometheus.io/port: 15090
              prometheus.io/scrape: true
              sidecar.istio.io/inject: false
Status:       Running
IP:           xx.xx.x.xx
IPs:
  IP:           xx.xx.x.xx
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/istio-egressgateway-5d6b6df7fd
Containers:
  istio-proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://2ad05a18267b829f381c18c7076a08fced64cd9b0990d3290115d6579fb16e12
    Image:         x/istio/proxyv2:1.7.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://x/istio/proxyv2@sha256:c1f1b45a4162509f86aa82d0148aef55824454e7204f27f23dddc9d7f4ae7cd1
    Ports:         8080/TCP, 8443/TCP, 15443/TCP, 8888/TCP, 15090/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      proxy
      router
      --domain
      $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
      --proxyLogLevel=warning
      --proxyComponentLogLevel=misc:error
      --log_output_level=default:info
      --serviceCluster
      istio-egressgateway
      --trust-domain=cluster.local
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 09 Dec 2020 11:20:02 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   128Mi
    Readiness:  http-get http://:15021/healthz/ready delay=1s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=30
    Environment:
      JWT_POLICY:                first-party-jwt
      PILOT_CERT_PROVIDER:       istiod
      CA_ADDR:                   istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
      NODE_NAME:                  (v1:spec.nodeName)
      POD_NAME:                  istio-egressgateway-5d6b6df7fd-gzkl6 (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:             istio-system (v1:metadata.namespace)
      INSTANCE_IP:                (v1:status.podIP)
      HOST_IP:                    (v1:status.hostIP)
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT:            (v1:spec.serviceAccountName)
      CANONICAL_SERVICE:          (v1:metadata.labels['service.istio.io/canonical-name'])
      CANONICAL_REVISION:         (v1:metadata.labels['service.istio.io/canonical-revision'])
      ISTIO_META_WORKLOAD_NAME:  istio-egressgateway
      ISTIO_META_OWNER:          kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/istio-egressgateway
      ISTIO_META_MESH_ID:        cluster.local
      ISTIO_META_ROUTER_MODE:    sni-dnat
      ISTIO_META_CLUSTER_ID:     Kubernetes
    Mounts:
      /etc/istio/config from config-volume (rw)
      /etc/istio/egressgateway-ca-certs from egressgateway-ca-certs (ro)
      /etc/istio/egressgateway-certs from egressgateway-certs (ro)
      /etc/istio/pod from podinfo (rw)
      /etc/istio/proxy from istio-envoy (rw)
      /var/run/ingress_gateway from gatewaysdsudspath (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/istio from istiod-ca-cert (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from istio-egressgateway-service-account-token-hmkc9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  istiod-ca-cert:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      istio-ca-root-cert
    Optional:  false
  podinfo:
    Type:  DownwardAPI (a volume populated by information about the pod)
    Items:
      metadata.labels -> labels
      metadata.annotations -> annotations
  istio-envoy:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  gatewaysdsudspath:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      istio
    Optional:  true
  egressgateway-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio-egressgateway-certs
    Optional:    true
  egressgateway-ca-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio-egressgateway-ca-certs
    Optional:    true
  istio-egressgateway-service-account-token-hmkc9:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio-egressgateway-service-account-token-hmkc9
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

**Service Entry**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: t-se-$(ENVIRONMENT)
spec:
  hosts:
    - t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
  ports:
    - number: 443
      name: https-t-se-$(ENVIRONMENT)
      protocol: HTTPS
    - number: 8888
      name: https-t-se2-$(ENVIRONMENT)
      protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_INTERNAL
```

**VM Service Entry**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: t-vm-se-$(ENVIRONMENT)
spec:
  hosts:
    - t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
  ports:
    - number: 8443
      name: https-t-vm-se-$(ENVIRONMENT)
      protocol: HTTPS
    - number: 8888
      name: https-t-vm-se2-$(ENVIRONMENT)
      protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

**Virtual Service**

Connections over port 443 are working as expected

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: t-vs-$(ENVIRONMENT)
spec:
  hosts:
    - t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
  gateways:
    - t-egressgateway-$(ENVIRONMENT)
    - mesh
  exportTo:
    - .
  tls:
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - mesh
          port: 443
          sniHosts:
            - t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
      route:
        - destination:
            host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 443
          weight: 100
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - t-egressgateway-$(ENVIRONMENT)
          port: 443
          sniHosts:
            - t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
      route:
        - destination:
            host: t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
            port:
              number: 8443
          weight: 100
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - mesh
          port: 8888
          sniHosts:
            - t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
      route:
        - destination:
            host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8888
          weight: 100
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - t-egressgateway-$(ENVIRONMENT)
          port: 8888
          sniHosts:
            - t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
      route:
        - destination:
            host: t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL)
            port:
              number: 8888
          weight: 100
```

**Getting Other Error Message**

When changing the targetPort in the istioOperator from 8888 to 8443 the log output from the istio-sidecare shifts from:

```
istio-proxy [2020-12-10T19:40:54.724Z] "- - -" 0 UF,URX "-" "-" 0 0 2 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "xx.xx.x.x:8888" outbound|8888||istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local - xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8888 xx.xx.x.x:34296 - -
```

to

```
istio-proxy [2020-12-10T19:43:08.341Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 517 0 1 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "xx.xx.x.x:8443" outbound|8888||istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local xx.xx.x.x:46252 xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8888 xx.xx.x.x:36660 t.$(ENVIRONMENT).$(BASE_DOMAIN_INTERNAL) -
```

But I can't see an entry in the egress-gateway log.

Problem now is probably, that the istio-egress pod ports now looks like this:

```
containers:
  ports:
  - containerPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 8443
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 15443
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 8443
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 15090
    name: http-envoy-prom
    protocol: TCP
```

Where it looked like this before:

```
containers:
  ports:
  - containerPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 8443
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 15443
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 8888
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 15090
    name: http-envoy-prom
    protocol: TCP
```

Comment: I assume you don't have any gateway for your egressgateway created yet? If you add port for your egress it won't show with netstat untill you create gateway which actually use it. For example, take gateway from [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/#egress-gateway-for-http-traffic) with egressgateway selector, change the port to 8888 and apply it.  If you check egressgateway with netstat now it should show port 8888. If that won't work could you add `kubectl describe` of your egress gateway?

Comment: As we can see in the kubectl describe this port 8888 is here, so it's configured properly. Do you have your [virtual service](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#TLSRoute) configured with appropriate host sni? AFAIK without it gateway with tls mode PASSTHROUGH won't show in your egress with netcat. It might actually show with AUTO_PASSTHROUGH as it do not require an associated VirtualService.

Comment: Okay, it seems that even with virtual service netcat doesn't show the port when tls mode PASSTHROUGH is active. When changing the mode to AUTO_PASSTHROUGH or the protocol to HTTP the port pops up in the gateway.
I'm still investigating why it then isn't working with PASSTHROUGH when everything for port 443/8443 seems ok

Comment: Hi @Lesrac, did you menage to make it work with PASSTHROUGH? Or you went with the AUTO_PASSTHROUGH mode and then everything works correct?

Comment: Hello @Jakub no I didn't got it running with PASSTHROUGH and AUTO_PASSTHROUGH can't be used. I haven't found a way yet to use the port 8888 in the gateway (or any other port additionally to the 8443)

Comment: That might be also related to your service entries, both defined on 8888, which might cause a port conflict, there is similar [case](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/25491) with that. I would recommend to open an [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues) with all the informations you gathered, so maybe istio devs could help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that and failed in the same way. The only option is to use the default ports unless istio gives another way to expose random ports through their container via settings